# Backgroundworker c# port listner

Tags: c#, port, backgroundworker

I am trying to stop my UDP listener that is running on `BackgroundWorker;` here is my code:

```
  private void bw_DoWork(object senderx, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = senderx as BackgroundWorker;

        while(true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("run");
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("cancel pending");
                e.Cancel = true;
                newsock.Close();
                serverStatus = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("waiting for reponse..");
                    data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);
                    (STUCK HERE IF NO RESPONSE)
```

So basically, if I do not get a UDP response, it will get stuck in the receive loop, and calling `bw.CancelAsync()` will not be checked.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: Your code isn't going to see CancellationPending when it is stuck inside the Receive call.  So don't use CancelAsync, close the socket instead.  Or just don't use BGW and use BeginReceive instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing asynchronous calls ans synchronous calls. You need to either make your recieve async or overload the `CancelAsync()` function to also close the socket (which will make the recieve call return).

If you cannot overload the `CancelAsync()` function, then you can create a custom cancel function which closes the socket and calls `CancelAsync()`.